# headers response in http.get

Tags: http, get, angular, wp-api

I spent hours trying to figure out how to get headers response like `x-total-objects` and status code after `http.get` request, I have this class service, and I need to access those attributes to paginate my results

in service:

```
@Injectable()
export class WPCollections{

  constructor(private http: Http){  }

  fetch(url){
     let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
     let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

     return this.http.get(url, options).map(res => res.json());
  }
}
```

in component:

```
@Input() args;
posts = new Array<any>();
service: Observable<any>;

constructor(private wp: WPCollections) { }

fetchData(args){
   this.service = this.wp.fetch(args);
   this.service.subscribe( 
     collection=>{
         this.posts = collection;
     },
     err => this.onError(err)

   );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact in your case you need to return the response object itself and not only the payload.

For this you to remove the map operator:

```
  fetch(url){
     let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
     let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

     return this.http.get(url, options);
  }
}
```

And in your component:

```
@Input() args;
posts = new Array<any>();
service: Observable<any>;

constructor(private wp: WPCollections) { }

fetchData(args){
   this.service = this.wp.fetch(args);
   this.service.subscribe( 
     response=>{
         this.posts = response.json();
       var headers = response.headers;
     },
     err => this.onError(err)

   );
}
```